# change featured product size on wordpress main page

Tags: css, wordpress

[image]

I've been trying to change the margin for featured products box on my homepage.
I was looking at style.css But I just couldn't find where. I am new to wordpress. please help. 
My website is [www.allmall.com.au](http://www.allmall.com.au)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The img has top and bottom margin:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a img,
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product a img {
    margin: 20px 0 !important;
```

that creates the extra space, and the

tag around the add-to-cart button has a bottom margin:

```
.woocommerce ul.products p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
```

that creates the space at the bottom.

You should learn to use the Chrome Developers Tools so you can look for such things yourself.

Comment: I appreciate for your help. However, I cannot find those codes in style.css